# Is it possible to enforce the size of int when using GCC?

Tags: gcc, int

It is well known that the size of int is implementation defined. Is it possible to specify the size of int to be a certain number in GCC, without changing the source code?

Comment: Why? Are you aware of the fixed-sized types in `stdint.h`?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It may be more flexible to change the size of int during compilation. Moreover, it's a useful feature to test portability.

Comment: I've checked through the options and couldn't find anything
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/index.html#toc_C-Implementation

Comment: Changing the size of `int` for an architecture would break ABI compatibility with pretty much every library, including the standard library. If you're testing, the best you can do is typedef your own integer type and use it throughout your library.